# Add text to each element of array

Tags: php

Basically what I am trying to do is add text before (and after) each element of an array. This is an example:

```
<?php 
    $word="code";
    $chars=preg_split('//', $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print"<pre>";
    print_r($chars);
    print"</pre>";
?>
```

(Yes I need the regex so I can't just use `str_split()`)

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => o
    [2] => d
    [3] => e
)
```

Now my ultimate goal is to get the final string to be something like:
`"shift+c","shift+o","shift+d","shift+e"`

If I can get help just adding the `"shift+` in front of each element, then I can use `implode()` to do the rest.

Comment: `array_map(function($c){return "shift+$c";},$chars)`

Comment: Why do you need the regex? This does the same `$chars = str_split('code')`

Comment: Because I am really pulling from an XML file and some of the arrays will be empty. It's easier for me to do `if(!empty){do described above}` then to see if the first element is empty. I am pretty new to PHP so that is the only way I can think of to bypass the empty arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on my comments:

```
$word = 'code';
$result = array_map(function($c){ return "shift+$c"; }, str_split($word));
```

And here's the output `var_dump($result)`:

```
array(4) { 
  [0]=> string(7) "shift+c" 
  [1]=> string(7) "shift+o" 
  [2]=> string(7) "shift+d" 
  [3]=> string(7) "shift+e"
}
```

**Edit:** If you really need to you can use the result from `preg_split` as the array in `array_map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the chars array and concatenate your desired string.

```
<?php 
    $word="code";
    $chars=preg_split('//', $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    foreach($chars as $c){
        echo "shift+" . $c . " ";
    }
?>
```

Outputs:

```
shift+c shift+o shift+d shift+e
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. elclanrs answer suites my needs better.